# ElasticSearch Nest - query on an array field

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have document that contains an array element:

```
{
...,
"roles": ["Worker", "Admin",...]
...
}
```

How can I create a query that returns all documents where on this array all values are NOT "client" for example?

Comment: you need to return document if roles doesn't have client , is that rght?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must not query in nest

```
var searchResults = this.elasticClient.Search<Model>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .MustNot(
                bs => bs.Term(p => p.roles, "client"),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: That did not work - could it be because roles is an array? I think that is my problem

Comment: Is field `roles` a nested field? That is it inside a **parent** field which is itself an array?
( I feel this snippet should have worked otherwise)

Comment: @DaniToker can you add the error and also mapping. Mapping you can get in kibana by running GET <index-name>/_mapping

Comment: "roles" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }

It is under properties

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your field `roles` is not nested, try the solution below.

```json
GET /<your-index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "roles": {
              "value": "client"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What mappings you have set for the field `roles` is important:

1. If you have mapping `text`, for the purposes of querying it will be stored as `roles: ["worker", "admin", "client"]`. This means your query must contain `"client"` (instead of `"Client"`).
2. If you have the mapping `keyword`, the values are stored "raw" and you should search with `"Client"`. If you don't know, just test the 2 possibilities.

Comment: Just noticed you wanted the solution for the c# nest client. But, I will leave the answer here in the hopes someone finds it useful.

Comment: I've tried running it on devtools and it didn't work - are you sure it works if roles is an array and not just a string/object?

Comment: With keyword suffix it will work in my case - thanks